# Sort opendir In Alphabetical Order

Tags: php, opendir

Is it possible to sort opendir into althabetical order?

```
$user = $fgmembersite->UserFullName();
$handle = opendir("users/$user/");

while (false!==($file = readdir($handle))) {
    if ($file != "." && $file != ".."){
        echo 'some code here';
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I asked a very similar question... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541510/php-readdir-not-returning-files-in-alphabetical-order

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use [`scandir()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php) instead:

```
$user = $fgmembersite->UserFullName();
$files = scandir('users/' . $user . '/');
foreach ($files as $file) {
    if ($file != '.' && $file != '..') {
        // Do stuff here
    }
}
```

As Blauesocke pointed out, it is already sorted.

Comment: I don't know much about PHP so what should I replace?

Comment: @CPFiles, Alright, I gave you a more full example with my last edit.