# how to load images from a directory in a sequence with php?

Tags: php, image, loading

I have this php code that works great, but the only thing is that images that are loaded from the folder are random, and I need them to load numerically by order.

`

```
//Open images directory
$dir = opendir("../blogimg/luda_jesus");


//List files in images directoryb
while (($file = readdir($dir)) !== false)
  {
      if(substr( $file, -3 ) == "jpg" )

      {
        echo "<div class='container'><img class='lazy' id='background'  src='../blogimg/loader.gif' data-original='../blogimg/luda_jesus/" . $file . "' width='884' height='587'></div>";

        //echo "<br />";

      }
  }

closedir($dir);

?>`
```

Please help me

Comment: How are the filenames constructed? Any way, take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541510/php-readdir-not-returning-files-in-alphabetical-order

Answer (score 1):

You can do this much more easily with [`glob`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php):

```
$files = glob("../blogimg/luda_jesus/*.jpg");
natsort($files); // can also use other sort functions here, take your pick
foreach ($files as $file) {
    echo '...';
}
```

I chose [`natsort`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php) as the sort function above because it will sort `2.jpg` before `10.jpg`, while plain `sort` will do the opposite. See [comparison of array sorting functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming "numerically" means by filename, you can simply do you while loop and populate all files in an array, sort it, and then load the files.

Example:

```
//Open images directory
$dir = opendir("../blogimg/luda_jesus");

//List files in images directoryb
while (($file = readdir($dir)) !== false) {
   if(substr( $file, -3 ) == "jpg" ) { 
     $filelist[] = $file;
   }
}

closedir($dir);
sort($filelist);

for($i=0; $i<count($filelist)-1; $i++) {
  echo "<div class='container'>
    <img class='lazy' id='background'  
      src='../blogimg/loader.gif' 
      data-original='../blogimg/luda_jesus/" . $file . "' 
      width='884' height='587'>
   </div>";
}
```

If you require different means of sorting, please mention so.