# Get first file in directory PHP

Tags: php, image, directory, user-profile

I want to get the first file in a directory using PHP.

I am trying to make a function where the users on my website can change their profile picture. To show their profile picture on their profile page I want to get the first image in their profile picture folder. I want to get the image they have uploaded, regardless of the file type. I have made it so when they upload a new picture the old one will be deleted, so it will just be one file in the folder. How do i do this?

Comment: It sounds like there will only be one image.  You could use glob('*') to get an array of files and choose the first (and only) one.

Comment: Can you share what you've tried or what you need help with. SO is not a 'do-it-for-me' place

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can get first file in directory like this

```
$directory = "path/to/file/";
$files = scandir ($directory);
$firstFile = $directory . $files[2];// because [0] = "." [1] = ".."
```

Then Open with [fopen()](http://php.net/fopen) you can use the w or w+ modes:

> **w** Open for writing only; place the file pointer at the beginning of
>   the file and truncate the file to zero length. If the file does not
>   exist, attempt to create it.

Answer (score 13):

```
$firstFile = scandir("path/to/file/")[2];
```

scandir: scans the given directory and puts into array: [0] = "." [1] = ".." [2] = "First File"

Comment: Why is [2] the first File? And what do the pots mean?

Comment: @skm on most non-windows systems '.' and '..' are mean 'this folder' and 'parent folder'. They are listed first by `scandir` making the first 'normal' file the third in the list.

Answer (score 3):

If the directory contains many files, it should be faster to use [readdir()](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.readdir.php) instead, because we do not write all files into an array:

```
if ($h = opendir($dir)) {
    while (($file = readdir($h)) !== false) {
        if ($file != '.' && $file != '..') {
            break;
        }
    }
    closedir($h);
}
echo "The first file in $dir is $file";
```

But note that [readdir does not return a sorted result](https://stackoverflow.com/a/541539/318765), so it does not return the most recent file.