# PHP readdir() not returning files in order

Tags: php, sorting, opendir

I have the below code that I run to list files within a directory. I would like to sort the output by some way. Preferably filename or by date of upload. Is this even possible?

```
<?php
  if ($handle = opendir('./xyz')) {
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
        if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
          $thelist .= '<a href="./abc/xyz/'.$file.'">'.$file.'</a><br>';
        }
    }
  closedir($handle);
  }
?>
<h1>List of files:</h1>
<ul><?php echo $thelist; ?></ul>
```

EDIT:
New code with update.

```
<?php
array_multisort(array_map('filectime', $files = glob('./xyz/*.*')), SORT_DEC, $files);
?>

<h1>List of files:</h1>
<ul><?php foreach($files as $file) {
    echo '<a href="./abc/'.$file.'">'.$file.'</a><br>';
}
?></ul>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP readdir() not returning files in alphabetical order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541510/php-readdir-not-returning-files-in-alphabetical-order)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't sort with `readdir` which reads them in the order that they are stored in the file system.  You can read them into an array and sort that. `array_multisort` works well and you can replace `filectime` with other functions:

```
array_multisort(array_map('filectime', $files = glob('./xyz/*.*')),
                SORT_ASC, $files);
```

- This gets all files into an array `$files`, maps to `filectime` to get the time, sorts on that and then sorts the `$files` array on that.
- For alphabetical just use `sort` or `rsort` after `glob`.

Once you have the sorted array just loop it and display or build your string as you were:

```
foreach($files as $file) {
    echo '<a href="./abc/xyz/'.$file.'">'.basename($file).'</a><br>';
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. How/where would I implement this into my code then?

Comment: Edited.  Build the array and then loop thru to display.

Comment: Great! Thanks, that works almost perfect. The only problem now is that it is displaying "./xyz/filename". Any way to have it show just the filename but still have the correct link?

Comment: Added `basename`

Answer (score -1):

have you tried use a kind of tranformation of the names in a Array, and after this tried to sorting ?...See this : is a basic sorting function

`<?php
$cars = array("Volvo", "BMW", "Toyota");
sort($cars);
?>`